# Join where one of the returned values is in a database named by an element returned from the join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to do a join of multiple tables. In one of the tables is the name of a database and I want a value from a table in that database to be returned as an element of the join.  No idea how to do it, but think of the "select top..." statement as the element that I want to retrieve in this psuedo-code:

```
SELECT app.Environment as Env, Dmn.DomainName as Domain, App.name as AppName, MgmtDb.Name as DBName, (select top (1) [VersionCode] from [MgmtDb.Name].[dbo].[VersionList] order by [Key] DESC)
FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MgmtDBs] MgmtDb 
JOIN [MyDB].[ZMFS_ITOPS].[dbo].[Application] App ON MgmtDb.application_ID = App.ID
JOIN [MyDB].[ZMFS_ITOPS].[dbo].[Domain] Dmn ON App.Domain_ID = Dmn.ID
```

How can I accomplish this?

UPDATE:

I've done some more work and this code generates a temp table with the data like I want, but I don't know how to create a view with that:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MonitorDBs') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MonitorDBs
SELECT app.Environment as Env, Dmn.DomainName as Domain, App.name as AppName, MgmtDb.Name as DBName, '               ' as SQLVersion
  INTO #MonitorDBs
  FROM [ITOPS].[dbo].[MgmtDBs] MgmtDb 
  JOIN [ITOPS].[dbo].[Application] App ON MgmtDb.application_ID = App.ID
  JOIN [ITOPS].[dbo].[Domain] Dmn ON App.Domain_ID = Dmn.ID

DECLARE @CurDBName as nvarchar(30)
DECLARE @SQL as nvarchar(1024)
DECLARE @MdbCursor Cursor   

SET @MdbCursor= Cursor FOR SELECT DBName FROM #MonitorDBs 
OPEN @MdbCursor       
FETCH NEXT FROM @MdbCursor INTO @CurDBName
WHILE (@@Fetch_Status = 0) 
BEGIN  
    set @SQL='IF OBJECT_ID(''' + @CurDBName + '.dbo.VersionList'') IS NOT NULL update #MonitorDBs set SQLVersion = (SELECT top 1 DLLVersionCode from [' + @CurDBName + '].[dbo].[VersionList] order by [Key] desc) where DBName = ''' + @CurDBName + '''' 
    --print @SQL
    exec(@SQL)
FETCH NEXT FROM @MdbCursor INTO @CurDBName
END

select * from #MonitorDBs
```

How can I make a view like this?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can accomplish this the way you're attempting in the above query (not the most performant). You just need a `WHERE` clause in the correlated subquery on the values you want to match. Another way you can do this is by using `OUTER APPLY` - similar to a `LEFT JOIN`. Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: The only way you can select from a database which is defined within the query is by using [dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and building a dynamic query. Have a go with that and come back with any questions.

Comment: @DaleK, I've added some code which gives me a query, but not sure how to make it into a view... or if there is a better query that I can do.

Comment: You can't create a view using dynamic SQL, you can only do it in a stored procedure. Good job on the dynamic SQL btw.

Comment: @DaleK, thanks for the assistance, but I've never gotten too deep into in SQL.  Are you saying that if I put this code in a stored procedure, I can then use that stored procedure to create a view?

Comment: No, there is no way to use dynamic SQL in a view. But a stored procedure can return a result set, so depending where you need these results you maybe able to execute a stored procedure and read the results. Thats the only way to do it in T-SQL. You could do something similar in code, but thats going to have similar issues.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK.  A stored proc might work ok for what I'm trying to accomplish.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as the comments suggest, you are looking to package your script into a stored procedure, this is all you need:

```
create procedure proc_MonitorDBs
as
begin

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MonitorDBs') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #MonitorDBs
    SELECT app.Environment as Env, Dmn.DomainName as Domain, App.name as AppName, MgmtDb.Name as DBName, '               ' as SQLVersion
    INTO #MonitorDBs
    FROM [ITOPS].[dbo].[MgmtDBs] MgmtDb 
    JOIN [ITOPS].[dbo].[Application] App ON MgmtDb.application_ID = App.ID
    JOIN [ITOPS].[dbo].[Domain] Dmn ON App.Domain_ID = Dmn.ID

    DECLARE @CurDBName as nvarchar(30)
    DECLARE @SQL as nvarchar(1024)
    DECLARE @MdbCursor Cursor   

    SET @MdbCursor= Cursor FOR SELECT DBName FROM #MonitorDBs 
    OPEN @MdbCursor       
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MdbCursor INTO @CurDBName
    WHILE (@@Fetch_Status = 0) 
    BEGIN  
        set @SQL='IF OBJECT_ID(''' + @CurDBName + '.dbo.VersionList'') IS NOT NULL update #MonitorDBs set SQLVersion = (SELECT top 1 DLLVersionCode from [' + @CurDBName + '].[dbo].[VersionList] order by [Key] desc) where DBName = ''' + @CurDBName + '''' 
        --print @SQL
        exec(@SQL)
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MdbCursor INTO @CurDBName
    END

    select * from #MonitorDBs

end
```

And then call it like this:

```
exec dbo.proc_MonitorDBs
```